# what's the best way to get multiple values from a perl array?

Tags: perl

For example,

First, I get the dataRecord into an array like this,

```
  my @dataRecord = split(/\n/);
```

Next, I filter on the array data record to get the test lines like this,

```
  @dataRecord = grep(/test_names/,@dataRecord);
```

Next, I need to get the test names from the test line like this,

```
   my ($test1_name,$test2_name,$test3_name)  = getTestName(@dataRecord);

   sub getTestName
   {
       my $str = shift @_;
       # testing the str for data and 
       print str,"\n"; # This test point works in that I see the whole test line.
       $str =~ m{/^test1 (.*), test2 (.*), test3 (.)/};
       print $1, "\n"; # This test point does not work. 
       return ($1,$2,$3);
    }
```

Is there a better way for me to acommplish this task?

Comment: what values are you expecting to get back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain operations together while reducing the syntax required.  This has the advantage of emphasizing the important parts of the program while reducing the syntax noise.

```
my @test = map m{/^test1 (.*), test2 (.*), test3 (.)/},
           grep /test_names/,
           split /\n/;

# use $test[0], $test[1], $test[2] here
```

If you are trying to debug a problem, map and grep can take blocks, making it easy to insert error checking code:

```
my @test = map {
               if (my @match = m{/^test1 (.*), test2 (.*), test3 (.)/}) {
                   @match
               } else {
                   die "regex did not match for: $_"
               }
           } # no comma here
           grep /test_names/,
           split /\n/;
```

Here are a few different ways to assign from an array that aren't directly related to your question, but are probably useful:

```
my ($zero, $one,  $two) = @array;
my (undef, $one,  $two) = @array;
my (undef, undef, $two) = @array;  # better written `my $two = $array[2];`

my ($one, $two) = @array[1, 2];    # note that 'array' is prefixed with a @
my ($one, $two) = @array[1 .. 2];  # indicating that you are requesting a list
                                   # in turn, the [subscript] sees list context
my @slice = @array[$start .. $stop];  # which lets you select ranges
```

To unpack the args to a subroutine:

```
my ($first, $second, @rest) = @_;
```

In a method that takes `name => value` pairs:

```
my ($self, %pairs) = @_;
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, how can I ensure no null values are enter into the @test array?

Comment: What type of null?  The value could be undefined, in which case `grep defined, ...`. The value could have no length, `grep length, ...`. The value could be zero, `grep $_ != 0, ...`.  Or it could be false, `grep $_, ...`.  Add any of these to the processing stack at the point where the erroneous values appear.

Comment: Thanks again Eric, I am getting Use of uninitialized value $str in pattern match (m//) error, which sounds like the value is not defined. This is a weird error because I thought grep will only capture the filter data you tell it to capture though each data record.

Comment: That's a warning coming from the `warnings` pragma that is letting you know one of the values you are trying to process is not defined.  In your case, it might mean that the regex that you are trying to match against has failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of matching subexpressions by using the `m//` operator in list context, for example by assigning its return value to a list of variables (like you currently do with the subroutine call). So, you can replace the subroutine with a much simpler construct:

```perl
my $str = shift @dataRecord;
my ($test1_name, $test2_name, $test3_name) =
    $str =~ m/^test1 (.*), test2 (.*), test3 (.)/;
```

Or, a `for` loop if you want to do this for each element of the `@dataRecord` array:

```perl
for my $str (@dataRecord) {
    my ($test1_name, $test2_name, $test3_name) =
        $str =~ m/^test1 (.*), test2 (.*), test3 (.)/;
}
```